# How to loop through and display data from multiple models in express using EJS on the index page

Tags: node.js, loops, express, ejs

I have 2 models (Revive and Launch). I would like to loop through both and display the data on one view (index.ejs)

Here is the router for Index:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Revive = require('../models/revive');
var Launch = require('../models/launch');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Revive.find({}, function (err, revives) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.render('pages/index', {revives: revives});
    }
  });
  Launch.find({}, function (err, launches) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.render('pages/index', {launches: launches});
    }
  });
});
```

And here is the view (index.ejs):

```
<% revives.forEach(function(revive) { %>

    <div class="copy">
        <p class="secondary">8.7/10 • Animation, Comedy</p>
        <h3 class="ellipsis"><h4><%= revive.reviveShowName %></h4></h3>
    </div>

<% }); %>

<% launches.forEach(function(launch) { %>

    <div class="copy">
        <p class="secondary">8.7/10 • Animation, Comedy</p>
        <h3 class="ellipsis"><h4><%= launch.launchShowName %></h4></h3>
    </div>

<% }); %>
```

While I'm able to loop through only one and display successfully as soon as I add the second loop it throws a header error 'launches is not defined...'

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution for all who run into the same issue:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Revive.find({}, function (err, revives) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      Launch.find({}, function (err, launches) {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          res.render('pages/index', {revives: revives, launches: launches});
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```